# Azure Active directory Logout

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I am using angular2 and for authentication and I am using azure active directory authentication.

For Logout from azure active directory authentication I am using below code:

```
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    localStorage.removeItem('useremail');

    window.localStorage.removeItem("id_token");
    window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token"); 
    window.localStorage.clear();   
     let link = ['/login'];
    this._router.navigate(link);
```

But it is not working. Everything I have tried. It actually redirect to login page but when again I do login it automatically login without any credential.

When I clear history manually it goes to login in azure server.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using this my problem is solved

window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + "{1}"

{0} is tendentid i.e. b8267886-f0c8-4160-ab6f-6e9343468fdc90

{1} is redirect url after logout i.e. http://localhost:5477/#/login

Comment: I know that this is an old topic. Your proposed solution might work, but the cleanest way is the one @Gary Liu - MSFT wrote, so this should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your original code snippet just clear your cache data saved in local storage, which didn't clean the server session on AAD IDP. In ng2, please use following code snippet to logout form AAD:

```
import {AdalService} from 'ng2-adal/core';
class whateverComponent{
    public logOut() {
        this.adalService.logOut();
    }
}
```

And we can direct to the source code to see what it will do when we call the function, [`AuthenticationContext.prototype.logOut`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L602)

Comment: If it helps, you can mark it as answer which may help other communities who may face the same issue.